# How to keep a <div> constant in size as the user zooms in and out on the page on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have been able to set the DIV content constant on all zoom levels on Chrome, Safari and Opera mini, but i cant get Mozilla to apply the same JavaScript code to set DIV constant on the browser on itself. When i set the zoom level more than 100% it sets all the div content as normal on chrome, safari and opera mini but on Mozilla it does the opposite, so I am asking how can i set this to be like the other web browser's and does Mozilla browser support the syntax in the JavaScript command below cause this is driving me nuts.

```
 //script to set DIV content constant as user zooms. NOT WORKING ON MOZILLA
 <script>
   function flostingDiva() {
     // How much the screen has been zoomed.
     var zoomLevel = screen.width / window.innerWidth;
     // By what factor we must scale the div for it to look the same.
     var inverseZoom = window.innerWidth/screen.width;
     // The div whose size we want to remain constant.
     var h = document.getElementById("scrollbox4");    

     // This ensures that the div stays at the top of the screen at all times. For some 
     // reason, the top value is affected by the zoom level of the Div. So we need to
     // multiple the top value by the zoom level for it to adjust to the zoom. 
     h.style.top = ((window.pageYOffset + 5) * zoomLevel).toString() + "px";

     // This ensures that the window stays on the right side of the screen at all times. 
     // Once again, we multiply by the zoom level so that the div's padding scales up.
     h.style.paddingLeft = ((window.pageXOffset + 5) * zoomLevel).toString() + "px";

     // Finally, we shrink the div on a scale of inverseZoom.
     h.style.zoom = inverseZoom;    
  }

  // We want the div to readjust every time there is a page load event:
  $(function() {
    floatingDiva();
  });        
</script>
```

Comment: Avoid ambiguous function names, they are harder to read and we won't know what they do when skimming the code. Most errors originate in bad coding manners.

Comment: FF uses `window.screen.width` afaik as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width

Comment: Try `zoomLevel=window.devicePixelRatio`. But see also [this discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292571).

Comment: @DarkMukke Firstly i am not detecting zoom level and secondly it works on chrome, Safari and Opera without any problem, that code, so I know there must be a fix to Firefox

Comment: I see a typo  function flostingDiva()

Comment: are you able to post a code snippet that actually runs, or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

zoom does not work in Firefox. you can use this code instead:

```
h.style.MozTransform = "scale(" + inverseZoom + ")";
h.style.MozTransformOrigin = ((window.pageYOffset + 5) * zoomLevel).toString() + " " + ((window.pageXOffset + 5) * zoomLevel).toString();
```

You can also use metas to set initial scale to 1 and prevent users to zoom in:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```